# How to replace a sequence of items in a collection, using other collections?

Tags: c#, collections, replace, sequence

Let's say I have an int array:

```
var source = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

I want to replace a portion of it using these arrays:

```
var fromArray = new int[] { 1, 2 };
var toArray = new int[] { 11, 12 };
```

The output I need to produce using the arrays above is: `11, 12, 3, 4, 5`.

In a more advanced scenario, I may also need to replace the source using multiple arguments. Think that `fromArray` and `toArray` are coming from a `Dictionary<int[], int[]>`:

```
IEnumerable<T> Replace(IEnumerable<T> source,
                       IDictionary<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> values)
{
    // "values" parameter holds the pairs that I want to replace.
    // "source" can be `IList<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T> if an indexer
    // is needed but I prefer `IEnumerable<T>`.
}
```

How can I achieve this?

**Edit:** The order of the items is important. Think it like `String.Replace`; if the whole content of the `fromArray` doesn't exist in `source` (if the source has only `1` and not `2`, for example) the method shouldn't try to replace it. An example:

```
var source = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var dict = new Dictionary<int[], int[]>();

// Should work, since 1 and 2 are consecutive in the source.
dict[new int[] { 1, 2 }] = new int[] { 11, 12 }; 

// There is no sequence that consists of 4 and 6, so the method should ignore it.
dict[new int[] { 4, 6 }] = new int[] { 13, 14 };

// Should work.
dict[new int[] { 5, 6 }] = new int[] { 15, 16 };

Replace(source, dict); // Output should be: 11, 12, 3, 4, 15, 16
```

Comment: PS, your signature isn't quite right, change values to have keys of IEnumerable<int>

Comment: @MAfifi - I don't get it, why?

Comment: You're going to try and index an array with type T.  That won't work because the indexer will always expect it to be an int.  See my example below.

Comment: Very inefficient and ugly way but works => convert lists to string and use string.Replace. `var dest = String.Join("", source.Select(x => "[" + x + "]"))
                                     .Replace(String.Join("", fromArray.Select(x => "[" + x + "]")), 
                                              String.Join("", toArray.Select(x => "[" + x + "]")))
                                     .Split(new char[]{'[',']'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                     .Select(x => Int32.Parse(x))
                                     .ToArray();`

Comment: Will `fromArray` and `toArray` always have a `Length` of two? After your edit, it looks like it could become important what order all the replacing is done in. However, the order of a `Dictionary<,>` is not well defined.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - No, sizes may vary.

Comment: @MAfifi IList<T> has an indexer that takes an integer and gets/sets a T. Indexer of the Array class also takes an integer (it implements IList anyway) and IEnumerable<T> interface doesn't have an indexer definition. So I have no idea what you're talking about. The T in IList<T> means "a list of T", not "a collection that uses T as indexer".

Comment: @L.B what if T doesn't have an overloaded + operator to be added with string?

Comment: @d4wn it is not related with overloded operator. `.ToString()` method of object is called.

Comment: @d4wn and you take the comment too seriously. If I had liked it, I would have posted it as answer.

Comment: @L.B - You spend time to provide help (comment or answer), I believe I should take it seriously. I didn't try it after I saw `x => "[" + x + "]"` because I didn't know that we can use + implicitly if the one side of it is a string so, thank you for that. I'll try it when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's an answer based on your edited question. Completely untested of course.

```
static IEnumerable<T> Replace<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IDictionary<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> values)
{
  foreach (var kvp in values)
    source = ReplaceOne(source, kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
  return source;
}

static IEnumerable<T> ReplaceOne<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> fromSeq, IEnumerable<T> toSeq)
{
  var sArr = source.ToArray();

  int replLength = fromSeq.Count();
  if (replLength != toSeq.Count())
    throw new NotSupportedException();

  for (int idx = 0; idx <= sArr.Length - replLength; idx++)
  {
    var testSeq = Enumerable.Range(idx, replLength).Select(i => sArr[i]);
    if (testSeq.SequenceEqual(fromSeq))
    {
      Array.Copy(toSeq.ToArray(), 0, sArr, idx, replLength);
      idx += replLength - 1;
    }
  }

  return sArr;
}
```

Comment: Seems nice, converting source to array and counting the values each time may hit the performance but like I said, I can use IList<T> instead of IEnumerable<T> if the Count and indexers are needed. I'll give it a try as soon as I can.

Comment: If `replLength` may be zero, you should put the `for` loop into an `if (replLength != 0)` block.

Comment: Also note, you might not be able to know in what order the `foreach` runs through the `IDictionary<,>`. If source is `a,b,c` and one replacement is `a→m` and another replacement is `c→a` (or `a→k`), then the order of the replacements matters. And you can't control that order well with a standard `Dictionary<,>`.

Comment: I thought Dictionary<T,T> iterates like List<T>, thanks for the info. Well, I may use IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T,T>> as the parameter type. Users of the method may want to use List<KeyValuePair<T,T>> e.t.c. depending on their needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work corretly,

```
    void Replace<T>(ref T[] source, IDictionary<T[], T[]> values)
    {
        int start = 0;
        int index = -1;
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            start = 0;

            while ((index = IndexOfSequence<T>(source, item.Key, start)) >= 0)
            {
                for (int i = index; i < index + item.Key.Length; i++)
                {
                    source[i] = item.Value[i - index];
                }

                start = index + item.Key.Length + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public int IndexOfSequence<T>(T[] source, T[] sequence, int start)
    {
        int j = -1;

        if (sequence.Length == 0)
            return j;

        for (int i = start; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            if (source[i].Equals(sequence[0]) && source.Length >= i + sequence.Length)
            {
                for (j = i + 1; j < i + sequence.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (!source[j].Equals(sequence[j - i]))
                        break;
                }

                if (j - i == sequence.Length)
                    return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: This is good. If `source` has repetitions, this solution only replaces one element in `source` for each `i`.

Answer (score 0):

If you love linq :)

```
var replaced = source.Zip(fromArray.Zip(toArray, (x, y) => new {From = x, To = y}),
                                      (x, y) => new {Src = x, Dest = y}).
                Select(x => x.Src == x.Dest.From ? x.Dest.To : x.Src);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<T> Replace(IEnumerable<T> source,
    IDictionary<IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<T>> values) 
{ 
    // "values" parameter holds the pairs that I want to replace. 
    // "source" can be `IList<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T> if an indexer 
    // is needed but I prefer `IEnumerable<T>`.

    IList<T> sourceAsList = source as IList<T>;
    if (sourceAsList == null)
    {
        sourceAsList = source.ToList();
    }

    foreach (var kvp in values)
    {
        // repeat same thing as above.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support general `IEnumerable<T>` (instead of arrays `T[]`), maybe something like:

```
IEnumerable<T> Replace<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> fromSeq, IEnumerable<T> toSeq)
{
  var dict = fromSeq.Zip(toSeq, (fr, to) => new { Fr = fr, To = to })
    .ToDictionary(a => a.Fr, a => a.To);

  foreach (var s in source)
  {
    T replace;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(s, out replace))
      yield return replace;
    else
      yield return s;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't see your edit about consecutive elements in `source`.