# Immutable collection in C# that supports (String-like) methods such as "Contains(IEnumerable<T>)"?

Tags: c#, string, collections, immutability

`String` class represents "a collection of chars" and is immutable. It's indexer has only get function defined and it's ok since `Char` "struct" is immutable as well. All of `String`'s methods that are used for manipulation return new instances of `String` class.

I recently needed an immutable generic collection that's *exactly* like `String` (Let's call it `Foo<T>`).

- It should be **generic** (though I'll only use it with structs).
- It should be **immutable**.
- It should have **methods for sequences** of items, for example:

  - `IndexOf(Foo<T>)` or `IndexOf(IEnumerable<T>)`
  - `StartsWith(Foo<T>)` or `StartsWith(IEnumerable<T>)`
  - `EndsWith(Foo<T>)` or `EndsWith(IEnumerable<T>)`
  - `Take(int, int)` (with start index and length, just like `Substring`)
  - `Contains(Foo<T>)` or `Contains(IEnumerable<T>)`
  - `LastIndexOf(Foo<T>)` or `LastIndexOf(IEnumerable<T>)`
  - etc.

I created an immutable class for read-only access to its items and wrote some extension methods to mimic String's functionality but I really have doubts about efficiency of my implementation (I actually asked for `Replace` method, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11913268/704144)). I'm curious about alternatives. Since `String` does everything I need (only to chars, unfortunately) it feels like re-inventing the wheel.

Simplest definition of what I need is "a generic String".

- Is there something like this in .NET or written for .NET?
- If not, some guidelines for creating one would be great.

---

**Edit after answers and comments:**

What I need is **not** a wrapper that will wrap a *specified* underlying, mutable collection and represent it as read-only. What I need is a truly immutable collection of `T` with methods to process **sequences of `T`**. Think `IList<T>.IndexOf(T)` for example, it gets the index of an **item**. Now think `String.IndexOf(String)` method, it (unlike the `IndexOf(Char)` method of `String`) gets the index of a **sequence** of chars and `String` has a lot of these kind of methods.

Now, why I don't use `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`: Apart from it doesn't support "*(String-like) methods such as Contains(IEnumerable)*", it also is **not** immutable. An example:

```
var array = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
var str = new string(array);
// array[2] is 'c' and str[2] is also 'c'
// I can't do str[2] = 'f', but:
array[2] = 'f';
// Now, array[2] is 'f' but str[2] is still 'c'
```

There is no way ([which is not a hack](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/are-strings-really-immutable-in-net/)) to change the state of a string. Now, let's take a look at `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`:

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var col = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(array);
// Here the col[2] is 3
// I can't do col[2] = 6, but:
array[2] = 6;
// Now the col[2] is 6 as well.
```

---

**Edit due to request - What I currently use:**

The collection (`Foo<T>`):

```
// Something I started like an hour ago. The only thing it does right now is to
// copy (not wrap) a specified enumerable and provide read-only access to it.
public sealed class Foo<T> : IList<T> where T: struct
{
    private readonly T[] _Array;

    public T this[int index] { get { return _Array[index]; } }
    IList<T>.this[int index]
    {
        get { return this[index]; }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }
    public Foo(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        // Enumerable.ToArray() method copies the content of the specified array.
        // Whetever happens to the "collection", value of "_Array" will stay the same. 
        _Array = collection.ToArray();
    }

    // Most of the methods of IList<T> are explicitly implemented. IsReadOnly
    // returns true and the methods that cause a change in collection throw
    // "NotSupportedException"s just like ReadOnlyCollection<T>.
    // IEnumerable<T> implementation uses an iterator block.
}
```

The extension methods:

```
// Extensions I used to manipulate collections so far.
// These are the things I want to get rid of.
public static class FooHelpers
{
     // I remove the bodies of these methods due to the confusion they have caused.
     // How they work is irrelevant and I posted these because of a request.
     public static bool Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
         IList<T> pattern) { }
     public static int IndexOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
         IList<T> pattern) { }
     public static int LastIndexOf<T>(this IList<T> collection,
         IList<T> pattern) { }
     public static IEnumerable<int> IndicesOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
         IList<T> pattern) { }
     public static IEnumerable<int> LastIndicesOf<T>(this IList<T> collection,
         IList<T> pattern) { }
     public static IEnumerable<T[]> Split(this IList<T> source,
         IList<T> seperator) { }
     public static bool StartsWith<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
         IList<T> pattern) { }
     public static bool EndsWith<T>(this IList<T> collection,
         IList<T> pattern) { }
     public static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IList<T> collection,
         int startIndex,
         int length) { }
     public static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
         int startIndex,
         int length) { }
     public static IEnumerable<T> TakeAll<T>(this IList<T> collection,
         int startIndex) { }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far? It should be easy enough to write this, and with the code you have written, we can point out where you might be going wrong.

Comment: @Tejs - I just wrote a class that has an Array in it. And I wrote some extension methods to provide manipulation features like:
`bool Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IList<T> pattern)`, `int IndexOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IList<T> pattern)`, `IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IList<T> collection, int startIndex, int length)` and it just felt wrong since there is already an implementation of the solution that I'm looking for. I'm curious about how String does these stuff.

Comment: See the [BclExtras](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/BclExtras) library

Comment: I don't see how immutability here is harming performance .. (IndexOf, Contains, etc, are not mutating and `yield` is lazy, albeit possibly "reference holding". It seems that a bigger issue, perhaps, is with clashing with the LINQ IEnumerable definitions/extension methods ..)

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert - I'm not looking for a review, I added the pieces I used so far because Tejs asked me so. And it has to be immutable. I don't get what ambiguity I created here, it felt wrong to re-invent the Wheel since there already is a class that does everythinh what I'm looking for to chars. I asked if anyone knows a generic version of it.

Comment: @pst - Enumerable class doesn't provide those extension methods which is why I wrote them in the first place. But you have a point. Well, I'm trying to get rid of them completely anyway.

Comment: But you cannot get true immutability because you cannot guarantee that the properties of each `T` cannot change?

Comment: @BobVale - True, to make it work I have to make sure that T is immutable first. The best I can do at this point is to use a type constraint and force T to be a struct but even this doesn't gurantee immutability since a struct can (but should not) be mutable. It's good enough for me, though.

Comment: Long road a struct could have a field which is a class which would not be immutable.  The only true way to achieve this would be to make deep copy of all items and then return a new deep copy of the item.  Whilst the copy would not be immutable atleast the source couldn't change.

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert - You are twisting my words. Of course there will be an underlying collection. The part you quoted there means that I can't use a mutable wrapper that wraps a specified collection. ReadOnlyCollection<T> holds the reference of the given collection, that means if you change it, the ReadOnlyCollection<T> will also change. That's why I needed to roll my class and prevent that. Sample in Bob's answer did exactly that. A collection that copies the specified collection so changing its reference has no impact on the created, immutable collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be 2 questions here:

1) Create an immutable collection

The short answer is **No**, there is no built in support for this.

the closest answer is really a `ReadOnlyCollection`, you could create a simple wrapper

```
public class ImmutableCollection<T> : ReadOnlyCollection<T> {

  public ImmutableCollection(IEnumerable<T> source) : base(source.ToList()) {}

}
```

The `ToList` call in the constructor makes a copy of the source collection so you can modify the source collection

Failing that you will have to implement your own class, probably inheriting from `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` and provide your own get accessor.

Either way you will have to bear in mind that each `T` cannot be guaranteed to be immutable (even with structs as the struct could have a field member that is a reference object).

But as you would still have to copy a source collection to make your collection imutable you would still be better off using the first example.

2) Provide extra functions to perform string like operations.

You would have to implement your own functions:

```
  public bool Contains(IEnumerable<T> pattern) {
   return IndicesOf(pattern).Any();
 }           

 public int IndexOf(IEnumerable<T> pattern) {
   return IndicesOf(pattern).Select(x=>(int?)x).FirstOrDefault() ?? -1;
 }           

 public int LastIndexOf(IEnumerable<T> pattern) {
   return IndicesOf(pattern).Select(x=>(int?)x).LastOrDefault()?? -1;
 }           

 public IEnumerable<int> IndicesOf(IEnumerable <T> pattern) {
  var count=pattern.Count();
  return Enumerable.Range(0,this.Count()-count).Where(i=> pattern.SequenceEqual(internalTake(i,count)));
 }           

 public IEnumerable<int> LastIndicesOf(IEnumerable<T> pattern) {
   return IndicesOf(pattern).Reverse(); // Could Optimize
 }

 private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> internalSplit(IEnumerable<T> seperator) {
   var splitPoints=this.IndicesOf(seperator);
   var length=seperator.Count();
   var lastCount=0;
   foreach(var point in splitPoints.Where(x=>!splitPoints.Any(y=>y<x && y+length>x))) {
        yield return this.Take(lastCount,point-lastCount);
        lastCount=point+length;
   }
   yield return this.TakeAll(lastCount);
 } 


 public ImmutableCollection<T>[] Split(IEnumerable<T> seperator) {
   return internalSplit(seperator).Select(x=>new ImmutableCollection<T>(x)).ToArray();
 }          

 public bool StartsWith(IEnumerable<T> pattern) {
    return pattern.SequenceEqual(this.Take(pattern.Count()));
 }           
 public bool EndsWith(IEnumerable<T> pattern) {
    return pattern.SequenceEqual(this.Skip(this.Count()-pattern.Count()));
 }           

 private IEnumerable<T> internalTake(int startIndex, int length) {
    var max=(length==-1) ? this.Count() : Math.Min(this.Count(),startIndex+length);
    for (int i=startIndex;i<max;i++) yield return this[i];
 }

 public ImmutableCollection<T> Take(int startIndex, int length) {
    return new ImmutableCollection<T>(internalTake(startIndex,length));
 }           

 public ImmutableCollection<T> TakeAll(int startIndex) {
    return new ImmutableCollection<T>(internalTake(startIndex,-1));
 }
```

Comment: @d4wn I've updated the answer to have the methods you ask for

Comment: Whoah, You're great! "You would have to implement your own functions" were satisfying alone (it was the answer of my question) but adding those methods? Thank you very much for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: List.AsReadOnly 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx

Comment: Does this allow doing `a.Contains(b)`, where the type of `a` and `b` are both of `IEnumerable<T>` or similar? (Where `Contains` here means in the "String sense", more verbosely named: `a.ContainsSequence(b)`.)

Comment: ReadOnlyCollection<T> is only a wrapper and the source may not. So it's not really immutable and it doesn't provide the features I need.

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert - `Char` is immutable. `String` is a collection of chars and it's also immutable. When you pass a an `Array` of chars to the `String`'s constructor, it copies the array. `N`th item of `String` won't change if you assign something new to the `N`th item of the `Char[]` you used to create the String. That's what makes it "immutable". On the other hand the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is just a "wrapper". If you get one using List<T>.AsReadOnly() and change the underlying list afterwards, the read-only collection will also be changed and that's what makes it mutable.

Comment: So you copy the source sequence first.. what's the big deal- this makes it like string

Comment: Anything you build to get solve this is the biggest version of source.ToList().AsReadOnly() anybody will ever see.. such a wasted effort

Answer (score 0):

If you want an efficient means of finding a subsequence your best best is probably going to be to write your own collection for the purpose.  I'd suggest using a `T[]` combined with an `int[]` to store the hash codes of every value.  One could then--to a significant degree--reduce the task of finding a sequence of `T` to finding a sequence of hash values.  It may be possible to convert a sequence of N hash codes into a string of 3N characters using 3 characters to store each hash code, and then use `string.Contains` or a regex parser to perform the sequence lookup.

Answer (score -1):

ReadOnlyCollection?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx

Comment: The point here is immutability and methods that can operate on sequences of items. ReadOnlyCollection<T> is mutable if the underlying collection is. And if the underlying collection is not mutable, then there is no need to use ReadOnlyCollection<T> anyway.

Comment: @d4wn: One can easily use `ReadOnlyCollection` to create an immutable collection from a mutable one by making a copy of the collection (e.g. using `ToList()`), wrapping that in a `ReadOnlyCollection`, and then destroying any outside reference to that collection.  Even if a class is mutable, *instances* may be immutable if there does not exist any means (absent Reflection-based cheating in full-trust environments) by which references to them could be exposed to code that would mutate them. Many if not most immutable classes hold private non-exposed instances of mutable types (e.g. arrays).

Comment: @supercat - Sure, Bob Vale's answer did exactly that. My point there was that ReadOnlyCollection<T> is not immutable by itself; it doesn't force the caller to copy the collection. It lets him choose the underlying collection on the contrary. That's why "derive from ReadOnlyCollection<T> and make it copy the given collection" is a real answer and "use ReadOnlyCollection<T>" is not (at least when it comes to this question).

Comment: @d4wn: I guess the question is whether one wants to create an instance of a collection and know that it won't change even if references to it, or the information used to create it, are exposed; or whether one wants to create a type which guarantees to any code that receives an instance that the instance in question will never change, no matter where it comes from.  `ReadOnlyCollection` can easily be used to provides the former, without having to derive any class from it.  If one needs the latter, deriving a *sealed* class from `ReadOnlyCollection` may be a good choice.

Comment: @supercat - I agree completely. If you just need to expose a private, mutable collection field in your class but you don't want it to be changed from outside your class then ReadOnlyCollection is a perfectly valid solution. I just think that a collection should _force_ this behavior in order to be immutable since an immutable type by definition cannot be changed after its initialization (hacks like accessing private members using reflection are exceptions). So creating a sealed class and forcing it to copy the given collection is, like you said the only way to achieve this.

Comment: @d4wn: The problem is that `ReadOnlyCollection` has two purposes: allowing a class to be made immutable, and allowing read-only access to mutable classes. A broader problem is that none of the collection interfaces allow a collection to indicate whether its length and/or the sequence of existing items might ever change (the length of an add-only list would not be immutable, but the sequence of existing items would). It would be ideal if an `ImmutableCollection` could perform a defensive copy if given a mutable collection but skip it if given an immutable one, but there's no way one could tell.

Comment: @supercat - Collection interfaces in .NET are insufficient in many ways (Array implements IList<T> because there is no other interface that has an integer indexer for example). Kevin Pilch-Bisson has a blog post about forcing immutability by the way ([Enforcing Immutability in Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kevinpilchbisson/archive/2007/11/20/enforcing-immutability-in-code.aspx)). I think that it can be usefull for seperating mutable types from immutable ones.

Comment: @d4wn: The blog post doesn't offer any mechanism for enforcing the very common scenario in which an immutable type holds the only extant reference to a mutable type, but doesn't mutate it (any immutable type containing an array must meet this pattern).  It also disparages exposed-field structs despite their great advantages when working with immutable classes (e.g. if the data for a class is wrapped in a struct and it includes a (possibly private) constructor that accepts an instance of that struct type, a method to return a class instance with a different value for some property can...

Comment: @d4wn: ...be written as `MyThing WithColor(Color newColor) {var temp = data; temp.Color = newColor; return new MyThing(temp);}`.  Note that the method associated with a property need not know anything about any other fields or properties of `MyThing`, nor any other fields within the structure.  Using that approach, the new thing would never have to be mutable outside its constructor.  The only other approach I can think of that would allow such methods to be written without each method having to know all the properties of the object would be to use `MemberwiseClone` and `private set`--icky.